# Set Location URI point to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller with an action and I want to set the `LocationUri` to point to another controller. For example, I have:

```
[Route("auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthorisationController
{
        [Route("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Put([FromRoute]string id, [FromBody]FooBar request)
        {
            return new CreatedResult("locationUri", SanitiseResponse(request));
        }
}
```

I want the `LocationUri` to point to this controller

```
[Route("transaction")]
[ApiController]
public class TransactionController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] string id)
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I do this? I was constructing it myself using `_httpContextAccessor` but wondered if there was a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where deriving from `ControllerBase` can help since it provides a helper member that simplifies what you are trying to achieve

```
[Route("auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthorisationController : ControllerBase {
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put([FromRoute]string id, [FromBody]FooBar request) {
        return CreatedAtAction("Get", "Transaction", { id = ??? }, SanitiseResponse(request));
    }
}
```

Reference [ControllerBase.CreatedAtAction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_CreatedAtAction_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_)

You still can do it yourself using the `CreatedAtActionResult`

```
[Route("auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthorisationController {
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put([FromRoute]string id, [FromBody]FooBar request) {
        return new CreatedAtActionResult("Get", "Transaction", { id = ??? }, SanitiseResponse(request));
    }
}
```

which is basically what the helper method wraps.

*Note the `???` in the exmaples where you would specify the `id` routeValue which in this case is part of the generated URI*

To avoid hard-coding the action and controller you can do the following, but I find it rather verbose.

```
//...

string actionName = nameof(TransactionController.Get);
string controllerName = nameof(TransactionController).TrimEnd("Controller");

return CreatedAtAction(actionName, controllerName, { id = ??? }, SanitiseResponse(request));

//...
```

If the controller name or action name is refactored, this would allow for the IDE to make the changes automatically or show a syntax error, alerting you to the change.

Comment: Thank you but I am getting an error saying "No route matches the supplied values". Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: @DrSchizo check updated answer. Note this answer is based specifically on the details you provided in the question. also what is the full error message?

Comment: I was using `nameof(TransactionController)` should just be `Transaction` like in your example.

Comment: @DrSchizo Yeah, I realized it was taking the full class name as well which is why I made the edit. Was trying to avoid using hard-coded strings to make refactoring easier. It is doable but would require more code to strip the "Controller" from the name.